# Integral with cross line

Tags: math-mode

[image]

Kindly send the latex code for this integral symbol

Comment: Here it is -- http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166246/34618

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{esint}
\begin{document}

\[ \fint_U f(\pi)\circ g(P) \]

\end{document}
```

[image]