# Contour integrals of different kind

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'm writing a paper on general mathematics and I want to add some contour integrals. The basic command is `$\oint$` which produces the known result: an integral with a circle in the middle.

How can I add the integral with the triangle in the middle and that of the box/rectangle in the middle? I have seen these symbols before but I don't know their code.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is this question helpful? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character

Comment: Wow... I managed to find the one symbol $\sqint$ but not the other with the triangle.

Comment: @Tolaso, what is the mathematical meaning of the triangle integral? Is it just to say that the closed curve is a triangle?

Comment: For display mode formula you can use `\triangle\llap{$\displaystyle\int$}` (but it is pour command).

Comment: @Sigur Yes... to denote that.. the closed curve is a triangle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's some possibility allowing you to easily define different integral symbols with decorations adapting to the math style:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\def\IntKern{}
\newcommand\MySymbolint[2][0pt]{%
  \mathchoice
  {\def\IntKern{\dimexpr-.6\wd0+#1\relax}\Symbolint\displaystyle\displaystyle{\scalebox{.8}{$#2$}}}%
  {\def\IntKern{\dimexpr-.62\wd0+#1\relax}\Symbolint\textstyle\textstyle{\scalebox{.6}{$#2$}}}%
  {\def\IntKern{\dimexpr-.642\wd0+#1\relax}\Symbolint\scriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle{\scalebox{.45}{$#2$}}}%
  {\def\IntKern{\dimexpr-.67\wd0+#1\relax}\Symbolint\scriptscriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle{\scalebox{.35}{$#2$}}}%
  \!\int}
\newcommand\Symbolint[3]{%
  {\setbox0=\hbox{$#1{#2#3}{\int}$ }%
  \vcenter{\hbox{$#2#3$ }}\kern\IntKern}
}
\def\uptriint{\MySymbolint\triangle}
\def\downtriint{\MySymbolint[0.31pt]{\rotatebox{180}{\raisebox{-2ex}{$\triangle$}}}}
\def\squareint{\MySymbolint\square}

\begin{document}

$
{\displaystyle\oint f}\quad \oint f\quad A_{\oint f} \quad A_{B_{\oint f}}
$

$
{\displaystyle\uptriint f}\quad \uptriint f\quad A_{\uptriint f} \quad A_{B_{\uptriint f}}
$

$
{\displaystyle\downtriint f}\quad \downtriint f\quad A_{\downtriint f} \quad A_{B_{\downtriint f}}
$

$
{\displaystyle\squareint f}\quad \squareint f\quad A_{\squareint f} \quad A_{B_{\squareint f}}
$

\end{document}
```

The code was adapted from [`this answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/760) to [Average integral symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/759)

Just for illustration of the method's versatility, here's a fancy integral sign built with the help of TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\MyBowTie{%
  \tikz[overlay]
  {
    \fill[cyan] (-0.45em,-0.5ex) -- (-0.45em,0.5ex) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
    \fill[orange] (0.45em,-0.5ex) -- (0.45em,0.5ex) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
  }
}

\def\IntKern{}
\newcommand\MySymbolint[2][0pt]{%
  \mathchoice
  {\def\IntKern{\dimexpr-.6\wd0+#1\relax}\Symbolint\displaystyle\displaystyle{\scalebox{.8}{$#2$}}}%
  {\def\IntKern{\dimexpr-.62\wd0+#1\relax}\Symbolint\textstyle\textstyle{\scalebox{.6}{$#2$}}}%
  {\def\IntKern{\dimexpr-.642\wd0+#1\relax}\Symbolint\scriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle{\scalebox{.45}{$#2$}}}%
  {\def\IntKern{\dimexpr-.67\wd0+#1\relax}\Symbolint\scriptscriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle{\scalebox{.35}{$#2$}}}%
  \!\int}
\newcommand\Symbolint[3]{%
  {\setbox0=\hbox{$#1{#2#3}{\int}$ }%
  \vcenter{\hbox{$#2#3$ }}\kern\IntKern}
}
\def\bowtieint{\MySymbolint\MyBowTie}

\begin{document}

$
{\displaystyle\bowtieint f}\quad \bowtieint f\quad _{\bowtieint f} \quad _{_{\bowtieint f}}
$

\end{document}
```

[image]